# Adjust layout to take a percentage of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

How can I make a custom view to take only 33% of the screen and make it show proportionately on every device?

This should be handled either on the xml files below, or in the custom view kotlin class, since it's part of a library  and I don't have access to the view that will host my custom class.

**buff_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/buff_sender"/>
    <include layout="@layout/buff_question"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/answersContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**buff_sender.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/light_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sender_image"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sender_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="4dp"
            tools:text="Praveen"
            android:textColor="@color/test_color_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buff_close"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**buff_question.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Where do you think Jorge will put this penalty? I'd go left here! Hehehehehehehehehehe super long text" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/question_time_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateDuration="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_time"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="14" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**buff_answer.xml (which will be injected in the answersContainer from buff_view.xml dynamically depending on the number of answers available for that question)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/light_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer_image"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_generic_answer"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/test_color_dark"
        tools:text="The keeper's right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**BuffView.kt**

```
class BuffView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null)
    : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val apiErrorHandler = ApiErrorHandler()
    private val getBuffUseCase = GetBuffUseCase(apiErrorHandler)

    private val intervalsHandler = Handler()

    private val buffView: LinearLayout = inflate(context, R.layout.buff_view, this) as LinearLayout

    private var errorListener: ErrorListener? = null

    private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null

    private var buffIdCount = 1

    private var getBuffs = false

    fun init() {
        getBuffs = true
        getBuff()
    }

    private fun getBuff() {
        if (!getBuffs) return
        getBuffUseCase.invoke(Params(buffIdCount.toLong()), object : UseCaseResponse<Buff> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: Buff) {
                displayBuff(result)
            }

            override fun onError(errorModel: ErrorModel?) {
                errorListener?.onError( errorModel?.message?: "An error has occurred")
                hideBuff()
            }
        })

        if (buffIdCount < TOTAL_BUFFS ) {
            intervalsHandler.postDelayed({
                buffIdCount++
                getBuff()
                stopCountDownTimer()
            }, REQUEST_BUFF_INTERVAL_TIME)
        }
    }

    private fun displayBuff(buff: Buff) {
        setQuestion(buff.question.title)
        setAuthor(buff.author)
        setAnswer(buff.answers)
        setProgressBar(buff.timeToShow)
        setCloseButton()
        invalidate()
        showBuff()
    }

    private fun setQuestion(questionText: String) {
        question_text.text = questionText
    }

    private fun setAuthor(author: Buff.Author) {
        val firstName = author.firstName
        val lastName = author.lastName
        sender_name.text = "$firstName $lastName"

        Glide.with(buffView)
            .load(author.image)
            .into(sender_image)
    }

    private fun setAnswer(answers: List<Buff.Answer>) {
        val answersContainer = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.answersContainer)
        answersContainer.removeAllViews()
        for(answer in answers) {
            val answerView: View = LayoutInflater.from(answersContainer.context).inflate(
                R.layout.buff_answer,
                answersContainer,
                false
            )

            answer.answerImage?.x0?.url?.let {
                Glide.with(buffView)
                    .load(it)
                    .into(answerView.answer_image)
            }

            answerView.setOnClickListener {
                answerView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.answer_selected_bg)
                answerView.answer_text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white))
                //freeze timer
                stopCountDownTimer()
                //hideView() after 2 seconds
                it.postDelayed(Runnable {
                    hideBuff()
                }, HIDE_BUFF_AFTER_SELECTED_ANSWER_DURATION)
            }

            answerView.answer_text?.text = answer.title
            answersContainer.addView(answerView)
        }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to include your buff_view.xml as a child of a layout where you can set the *layout_weight* property like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <include layout="@layout/buff_view">
        
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also change the width and height constraints for the buff view top LinearLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/buff_sender"/>
    <include layout="@layout/buff_question"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/answersContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***EDIT***: Progress bar not visible problem

I think it is a problem with the TextView *question_text*

Change it like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:padding="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Also change the main Layout in *buff_question.xml* and set its *layout_width* to **match_parent** like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works, the only problem that I am finding is that the progress bar contained in the buff_question.xml file is not visible like this. Any ideas on how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done using `ConstraintLayout` and width/height percentages.
Be sure to set the *actual* width dimensions to `0dp` (where using a percentage value) and to make sure the views are constrained appropriately.

The below produces this output

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:background="@color/salmon1"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".33"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:background="@color/orange1"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't use a ConstraintLayout. My buff_view needs to be a LinearLayout.

Comment: Why does it need to be a LinearLayout?